# How to get the Annotation value from Java file using Groovy?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, groovy

I want to print the annotation details of a Java file in Android using Android Studio and Groovy.

Comment: Java File?  Or instance of a Java object?  Or reference to Java Class?  Also, I hope they're `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` annotations (unless you mean File, and you want to do some text parsing)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean you have a Java class and you want to list it's annotations.

And assuming those annotations are `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`, so they're still visible when the code is running

You can do something like this:

```
List<String> annotations = ClassOfInterest.annotations.collect { it.annotationType().name }
```